# The Monte Carlo method for estimating pi in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to estimate the value of pi using the Monte Carlo method, this is, A random number generator can be used to estimate the value of pi. So I have found the following code

```
n=input('Number of points: ');
x=rand(n,1);
y=rand(n,1);
figure('color','white');
hold all

axis square;
x1=x-0.5;
y1=y-0.5; %cirle has centre at (0.5,0.5)
r=x1.^2+y1.^2;
m=0;   %Number of points inside circle
for i=1:n
    if r(i)<=0.25
        m=m+1;
        plot(x(i),y(i),'b.');
    else

        plot(x(i),y(i),'r.');
    end
end
m/(0.25*n)
```

The thing is How Can I modify it so it gives me a square of length 2 and a circle of radius 1?

I've done this so far but it only give a quarter of what is suppose to give me:

```
n=input('Number of points: ');
x=rand(n,1);
y=rand(n,1);
figure('color','white');
hold all

axis square;
axis ([0 2 0 2])
x1=x-1;
y1=y-1; %cirle has centre at (0.5,0.5)
r=x1.^2+y1.^2;
m=0;   %Number of points inside circle
for i=1:n
    if r(i)<=1
        m=m+1;
        plot(x(i),y(i),'b.');
    else

        plot(x(i),y(i),'r.');
    end
end
m/(0.25*n)
```

NOTE: the method is the following: generate random points in a square with sides of length 2 and count what proportion of these points falls in the unit radius circle that fits exactly into the square.This proportion will be the ratio of the area of the circle to the area of the square, hence, this estimates pi.

Comment: Are you familiar with matlab and geometry?

Comment: Then I suggest first getting familiar with both:) Only a little is needed in both areas to change the "code you have found" to the one you need. We won't write your homework.

Comment: Well is not homework, is practice but since I have thought in this code for a long time and I don't have great skills programming I was thinking in help from you :)

Comment: Is there any programming language you know? Why matlab, if you're unfamiliar with it? This algorithm can be easily programmed in virtually any language, apart from the plotting part.

Comment: Well I thought in MATLAB because it will be useful for me in the future and this code was taken from the notes of a student that had a course in matlab a long time ago jajaj but I only thought that is could only need slightly modifications but I can't figure out how to get all the plot, not only the quarter part I've got, and it doesn't matter the plot, the thing that is important in fact is the approximation but I don't know how to modify to have only the number and not the plot since it is a part of a for loop :)

Comment: Then what can be done ?

Comment: your problem is that you didn't scale your 'x' and 'y' to the range [0 2]

Comment: Ok, and you did that in your post right?

Answer (score 1):

Try that

```
n=input('Number of points: ');
x=2*rand(n,1);
y=2*rand(n,1);
figure('color','white');
hold all

axis square;
x1=x-1;
y1=y-1; %cirle has centre at (1,1)
r=x1.^2+y1.^2;
m=0;   %Number of points inside circle

ii = r<=1;
m = sum(ii);
plot(x(ii), y(ii), '.b');
plot(x(~ii), y(~ii), '.r');

m/(0.25*n)
```

Comment: Ok let me try it :), if there is some problem can I tell you :)?

Comment: And you scaled 'x' and 'y' to the range [0 2] right?

Comment: right - the rand function produce uniformly distributed number between 0-1 that's why you need to multiply that by two if you want points between 0-2

Comment: Ok, then just let me try it and lets see :)